# How to integrate paytm wallet in android application?

Tags: java, android

I want to integrate paytm wallet in my android application. I found lots of suggestions and documentation on Google but nothing worked. If there is any documentation, code samples or useful suggestions that you know please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this link http://paywithpaytm.com/developer.html

Comment: Use this link here is the sample https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Android_App_Kit

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Note: Below is for version 1.0, now paytm updated their sdk, so you need to change that accordingly.
Go to link :

### http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/

and download Android+SDK

put below code in your function or where you want to start paytm stuff.

```
    private int randomInt = 0;
    private PaytmPGService Service = null;

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);
    //for testing environment   
    Service = PaytmPGService.getStagingService();
    //for production environment 
    /*Service = PaytmPGService.getProductionService();*/ 

    /*PaytmMerchant constructor takes two parameters
    1) Checksum generation url
    2) Checksum verification url
    Merchant should replace the below values with his values*/


PaytmMerchant Merchant = new PaytmMerchant("https://pguat.paytm.com/merchant-chksum/ChecksumGenerator","https://pguat.paytm.com/merchant-chksum/ValidateChksum");

    //below parameter map is required to construct PaytmOrder object, Merchant should replace below map values with his own values

    Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        //these are mandatory parameters
        paramMap.put("REQUEST_TYPE", "DEFAULT");
        paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", String.valueOf(randomInt));
        //MID provided by paytm
        paramMap.put("MID", "id provided by paytm");
        paramMap.put("CUST_ID", "CUST123");
        paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WAP");
        paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");
        paramMap.put("WEBSITE", "paytm");
        paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "1");
        paramMap.put("THEME", "merchant");          
                                    
        PaytmOrder Order = new PaytmOrder(paramMap);


Service.initialize(Order, Merchant,null);
        Service.startPaymentTransaction(activity, false, false, new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTransactionSuccess(Bundle bundle) {
            app.getLogger().error("Transaction Success :" + bundle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransactionFailure(String s, Bundle bundle) {
            app.getLogger().error("Transaction Failure :" + s + "\n" + bundle);
        }

        @Override
        public void networkNotAvailable() {
            app.getLogger().error("network unavailable :");
        }

        @Override
        public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String s) {
            app.getLogger().error("clientAuthenticationFailed :" + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void someUIErrorOccurred(String s) {
            app.getLogger().error("someUIErrorOccurred :" + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int i, String s, String s2) {
            app.getLogger().error("errorLoadingWebPage :" + i + "\n" + s + "\n" + s2);
        }
    });
    }
```

Also another thing is you need to declare one activity in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Hope above code sample will help u lot.
Also another thing is when you download Android+SDK you will get one jar file pgsdk.jar file that you need to add in your project and MainActivity.java class file for our reference. Enjoy!!!

Note: ChecksumGenerator and ValidateChksum urls are for just testing purpose which is provided by paytm development support team. You need to generate it on your own server for redirecting respective url.

Comment: How I get the merchant checksum url  or Can I  use the given checksum url which is given in your code. Only required Merchant id or All the things like checksum url and merchant , both are provided by Paytm

Comment: Contact to paytm development support team and they will give you checksum generation and checksum validation code including merchant id and all necessary things that you need to deploy in your server.

Comment: I am not able to redirect to the verifychecksum page.  after transaction, its redirect to paytm.com page. whats issue here any idea?

Comment: @MihirShah have you got what is merchant checksum url ?

Comment: I am not able to redirect to the verifychecksum page. after transaction, its redirect to paytm.com page. whats issue here any idea?me also...any idea

Comment: @GaneshKatikar I have Merchant key and Merchant Id, How to generate those Urls to use in my App.

Comment: Paytm support team will provide you a checksum validation and checksum generation code files that you need to add/integrate in your server and replace the absolute path/url of both in the above code.
PS: Please check current documentation of paytm for architecture changes.

Comment: This is for Version 1.0, in Version 2.0 we cann't pass PaytmMerchant object in Service.initialize method.

Comment: Yeah, It may be possible that they did some changes in version 2.0. You are always welcome if you know that change and edit it if possible.