# I am trying to integrate PayTM with my android app using the following code

Tags: android, oop, sandbox, staging, paytm

However I am getting a screen that says "Oops! Payment failed" after i click on the start_transaction button. Can someone please help? I have not included the staging credentials that have been given to me by paytm in the code below.

```
    package in.wishup.assistant.fragments.PaymentDialogFragments;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Random;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.DialogFragment;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import butterknife.Bind;
    import in.wishup.assistant.R;
    import com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmClientCertificate;
    import com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmMerchant;
    import com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmOrder;
    import com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGService;
    import com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback;

/**
  * Created by DELL on 7/4/2016.
 */
public class PaytmFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private Context mContext;
Button btn_pay;


public PaytmFragment()
{}

public PaytmFragment(Context mContext)
{
    this.mContext=mContext;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);
    btn_pay = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.start_transaction);
    //setListeners();
    btn_pay.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.start_transaction : Log.d("paytm","button pressed");
            pay();
            break;
    }
}
private void pay()
{
    Log.d("paytm","inside pay");
    //Getting the Service Instance. PaytmPGService.getStagingService()  will     return the Service pointing to Staging Environment and     PaytmPGService.getProductionService() will return the Service pointing to     Production Environment.
    PaytmPGService Service = null;

    Service = PaytmPGService.getStagingService();
//or
    Service = PaytmPGService.getProductionService();
//Create new order Object having all order information.
         Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        paramMap.put("REQUEST_TYPE", "DEFAULT");
        paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", "ORDER12350");
        paramMap.put("MID", "xxxxx");
        paramMap.put("CUST_ID","CUST110");
        paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WAP");
        paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");
        paramMap.put("WEBSITE", "paytm");
        paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "1.0");
        paramMap.put("THEME ", "merchant");
        paramMap.put("EMAIL","xxx");
        paramMap.put("MOBILE_NO","7777777777");

        PaytmOrder Order = new PaytmOrder(paramMap);
//Create new Merchant Object having all merchant configuration.

        PaytmMerchant Merchant = new PaytmMerchant( "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumGenerator.jsp", "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumVerify.jsp");

//Set PaytmOrder and PaytmMerchant objects. Call this method and set both objects before starting transaction.
    Service.initialize(Order, Merchant, null);

//Start the Payment Transaction. Before starting the transaction ensure that initialize method is called.
    Service.startPaymentTransaction(mContext, true, true, new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback()
    {


        @Override
        public void onBackPressedCancelTransaction() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void someUIErrorOccurred(String inErrorMessage)
        {
            // Some UI Error Occurred in Payment Gateway Activity.
            // This may be due to initialization of views in Payment Gateway Activity or may be due to initialization of webview.
            // Error Message details the error occurred.
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Some UI error occurred",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransactionSuccess(Bundle  inResponse)
        {
            // After successful transaction this method gets called.
            // Response bundle contains the merchant response parameters.
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Transaction successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransactionFailure(String inErrorMessage, Bundle  inResponse)
        {
            // This method gets called if transaction failed.
            // Here in this case transaction is completed, but with a failure.
            // Error Message describes the reason for failure.
            // Response bundle contains the merchant response parameters.
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Transaction failure",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        public void networkNotAvailable()
        {
            // If network is not available, then this method gets called.
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Network not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String  inErrorMessage)
        {
            // This method gets called if client authentication failed.
            // Failure may be due to following reasons
            //      1. Server error or downtime.
            //      2. Server unable to generate checksum or checksum response is
            //         not in proper format.
            //      3. Server failed to authenticate that client. That is value of
            //         payt_STATUS is 2.
            // Error Message describes the reason for failure.
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Client authentication failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int iniErrorCode, String inErrorMessage, String inFailingURL)
        {
            // This page gets called if some error occurred while loading some URL in Webview.
            // Error Code and Error Message describes the error.
            // Failing URL is the URL that failed to load.
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Error loading webpage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And this is where I create the object of this class:

```
FragmentManager fm2=getFragmentManager();
                Log.d("paytm","made it inside paytm!!");
               PaytmFragment paytmFragment=new PaytmFragment(mContext);
                paytmFragment.show(fm2,null);
```

Comment: I edited it. Please check.

Comment: Replace
`Service.startPaymentTransaction() ;`
from http://stackoverflow.com/a/30069763/4035628

Comment: @kashyapjimuliya I am still getting the same errors

Comment: are you getting any Toast Message?

Comment: no I am not getting it.

Comment: @Debbie is your problem solved ??

Comment: yes! the checksum generation and validation URLs were incorrect.

Comment: @kashyapjimuliya can you help me with citrus wallet integration in android?

Comment: i created staging details as a merchant.i dont see any checksum url.I am new to paytm integration.Please Help

Comment: Check my ans here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342477/oops-payment-failed-due-to-any-of-this-reasons-when-trying-to-call-paytm-servi/47899946#47899946

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put these values -

```
paramMap.put("MID", "xxxxx");
paramMap.put("EMAIL","xxx");
paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "xxxxx");
```

Your website value is looking default, please replace these values by the values you got from paytm.
And remove this line -

```
Service = PaytmPGService.getProductionService();
```

It's for production, when you are releasing your app to play-store.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Let me know if you need more help :)

Comment: Thanks but I am still getting the same error. There is probably a problem in resolving a host name

Comment: Can u please post your updated code and complete logcat

Comment: I just removed the line u asked me to. The other values have been added but ?I cannot share them.

Comment: I added the logcat

Comment: Your post doesn't contains complete logs, Kindly filter your log with PGSDK and update.

Comment: I have added them now.

Comment: @Debbie your part is done now, No need to make any change from your side. Now paytm will do the rest. Just attach the same logcat, take a screenshot and send it to the paytm tech.ops@paytm.com . They will take care and fix it. One thing you need to take care that everytime the order id must differ. So if the problem not fixed by simply changing order id, then send all to them and relax. You have done your part :)

Comment: And remove your logcat from your post, it has all your paytm secret ids.